# How to convert from flex UI to apache roayle

Tags: apache-flex, apache-royale

I have Main.MXML file within that I have another view ReportTab.mxml(canvas is root tag for this page) under this one I have more another page RaviReport.mxml(canvas is root tag for this page) within this page I having formItem once I submit them I need to get the data from Backed using RemoteObject tag and I have to render data in DATAGRID. When I am loading my Main.mxml file I can able to compile successfully but I am getting error in console.
**EventDispatcher.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: indicatorClass is not a constructor
    at mx.containers.FormItem.mx_containers_FormItem_displayIndicator (FormItem.js:718)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.updateDisplayList (FormItem.js:397)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.updateFormItemDisplayList (FormItem.js:409)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.updateDisplayList (FormItem.js:1101)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.mx.containers.beads.BoxLayout.layout (BoxLayout.js:115)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.org.apache.royale.core.LayoutBase.performLayout (LayoutBase.js:247)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.org.apache.royale.core.LayoutBase.handleLayoutNeeded (LayoutBase.js:152)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.goog.events.EventTarget.fireListeners (eventtarget.js:284)
    at Function.goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEventInternal_ (eventtarget.js:381)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (eventtarget.js:196**

I have tried removing FormItem and I have just added  in RaviReport.mxml but My canvas is hiding the label element. Please suggest me how to integrate view within using navigationBar or ViewSTACK in Royale.

**Main.MXML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:view="com.sp.cpem.view.*" backgroundColor="#FFFFFF" verticalGap="0" horizontalGap="0" paddingTop="0" paddingLeft="2" paddingRight="2" paddingBottom="2" pageTitle="EXAMPLE">

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

    ]]>

    </mx:Script>


        <mx:ViewStack id="myViewStack" borderStyle="none" width="100%" height="100%">           

            <view:ReportTAB id ="repo" label="REPORTING" />

        </mx:ViewStack>        
</mx:Application>


**ReportTAB.MXML:**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:view="com.sp.cpem.view.reports.*" width="100%" height="100%">
        <mx:TabNavigator width="100%" height="100%">

            <view:RaviReport id = "raviReport" label="Ravi Report"/>
        </mx:TabNavigator>
</mx:Canvas>   



**RaviReport.MXML:**


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:view="com.sp.cpem.view.*" width="100%" height="100%" creationComplete="loadPage();">
    <mx:RemoteObject id="pageService" destination="pageService" result="handlePageResult(event)"  fault="handleFault(event)" showBusyCursor="true" />
    <mx:RemoteObject id="loaderService" destination="reportService" result="handleLoadResult(event)"  fault="handleFault(event)" showBusyCursor="true" />   

    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.sp.cpem.vo.StarsStdValues;
        import mx.managers.CursorManager;
        import com.as3xls.xls.Sheet;
        import com.as3xls.xls.ExcelFile;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;                                         
        import mx.rpc.events.FaultEvent;
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;    
        import flash.net.FileReference;
        import mx.controls.Alert;

        private var pageArray:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        private var fileReference:FileReference;
        private var sheet:Sheet;

        [Bindable]
        private var reportDG:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        [Bindable]
        private var assetDP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        [Bindable]
        private var locationDP:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();
        [Bindable]
        private var fields:Array = new Array();  
        [Bindable]                               
        public var abcpRecords:int = 0;

        public var d:Date = null;

        import flash.external.*;

        private function exportToExcel():void{
            if(fromDate.selectedDate == null || toDate.selectedDate == null || asset.selectedItem == null || location.selectedItem == null )
                    Alert.show("Please input '*' required fields.","Information", Alert.OK, null, null, null, Alert.OK);                
            else{
                var s:String;
                var locStr:String;
                d = DateField.stringToDate(toDate.text, toDate.formatString);               
                d.hours = 23;
                d.minutes = 59;
                d.seconds = 59;
                d.milliseconds = 999;
                locStr='';
                //var myArray:Array = new Array(10);                
                var myArray:Array = location.selectedItems;             
                var obj:StarsStdValues;
                for (var i:uint; i < myArray.length; i++) {
                    obj = myArray[i];                   
                    if(i==0)
                        locStr = obj.value;
                    else
                        locStr = locStr+","+obj.value;
                }                           
                if (ExternalInterface.available) {
                    var formatter : DateFormatter;
                    formatter = new DateFormatter();
                    formatter.formatString = "DD.MMMM.YYYY KK:NN:SS A";
                    var jsFunction:String = "toABCPExcel";                      
                    s = ExternalInterface.call(jsFunction,formatter.format(fromDate.selectedDate),formatter.format(d),locStr);
                } else {
                    s = "JS not available";
                }
            }
        }

        /* We are using JSP to create report not FLEX due to 255 char limit issue
        private function exportToExcel1():void
        {   
            sheet = new Sheet();
            var dataProviderCollection:ArrayCollection = dataGrid.dataProvider as ArrayCollection;
            var rowCount:int =  dataProviderCollection.length;
            var columns:Array = dataGrid.columns;
            var colCount:int =columns.length; 
            sheet.resize(rowCount+4,colCount);
            var i:int = 0;  
            for each (var field:DataGridColumn in columns){
                fields.push(field.dataField.toString());                
                sheet.setCell(0,i,field.headerText.toString());  
                i++;  
            }

            for(var r:int=0;r<rowCount;r++)
            {
                var record:Object = dataProviderCollection.getItemAt(r);
                /*insert record starting from row no 2 else 
                    headers will be overwritten* /
                insertRecordInSheet(r+1,sheet,record);
            }
            var xls:ExcelFile = new ExcelFile();
            xls.sheets.addItem(sheet);

            var bytes:ByteArray = xls.saveToByteArray();
            var fr:FileReference = new FileReference();      
            fr.save(bytes,"LOCExposureReport.xls");            

        }
        private function insertRecordInSheet(row:int,sheet:Sheet, record:Object):void
        {                   
            var i:int = 0;  
            for each(var field:String in fields){  
                if(record[field] == null){
                    //Do nothing if its null        
                }else{                              
                    sheet.setCell(row,i,record[field].toString());                    
               } 
               i++;
            }
            //Alert.show(record["comments"].toString(),"Information", Alert.OK, null, null, null, Alert.OK);            
        }*/

            public function loadPage():void {               
                pageService.getDP("ABCPReport");        
            }
            private function handlePageResult(ev:ResultEvent):void {
                 pageArray = ev.result as ArrayCollection;               
                 assetDP =pageArray[0] as ArrayCollection;
                 locationDP =pageArray[1] as ArrayCollection;
                 asset.selectedIndex = 0;
                 location.selectedIndex = 0;

            }

                public function getReport():void {
                //Alert.show(toDate.value.toString(),"Information", Alert.OK, null, null, null, Alert.OK);
                d = DateField.stringToDate(toDate.text, toDate.formatString);               
                d.hours = 23;
                d.minutes = 59;
                d.seconds = 59;
                d.milliseconds = 999;
                //toDate.selectedDate = d;              
                //toDate.selectedDate = DateField.dateToString(d, toDate.formatString);             

                if(fromDate.selectedDate == null || toDate.selectedDate == null || asset.selectedItem == null || location.selectedItem == null )
                    Alert.show("Please input '*' required fields.","Information", Alert.OK, null, null, null, Alert.OK);                
                else                            
                    loaderService.getReport(asset.selectedItems,fromDate.selectedDate,d,location.selectedItems); //toDate.selectedDate                  
            }

            private function handleLoadResult(ev:ResultEvent):void {
                 reportDG = ev.result as ArrayCollection;
                 abcpRecords = reportDG.length;
                 this.label = "ABCP Exposure Report (" +abcpRecords +")";    
            }

            private function handleFault(ev:FaultEvent):void {                
                Alert.show("Error: " + ev.fault.faultCode + " - " + ev.fault.faultDetail + " - " + ev.fault.faultString,"Information", Alert.OK, null, null, null, Alert.OK);   
            }   

            private function dateFunc( item:Object, column:DataGridColumn):String
            {
                return formatDate.format(item[column.dataField]);
            }

            //NUMERIC SORTING obj1[fieldName] sortCompareFunction="sortNumeric" 
            private function sortMaturityDate(obj1:Object, obj2:Object):int {
                var value1:Date = (obj1.strmaturityDate =='' || obj1.strmaturityDate == null) ? null : new Date(obj1.strmaturityDate);
                var value2:Date = (obj2.strmaturityDate == '' || obj2.strmaturityDate == null) ? null : new Date(obj2.strmaturityDate);
                if (value1 < value2) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (value1 > value2) {
                    return 1;
                } else {
                    return 0;
                }
            }
        ]]> 

    </mx:Script>
    <mx:DateFormatter id="formatDate" formatString ="D-MMM-YYYY"/>  
    <mx:VDividedBox width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:HBox height="15%" width="100%">
                <mx:FormItem label="Location:" required="true">
                    <mx:List id="location" dataProvider="{locationDP}" labelField="value" allowMultipleSelection="true" rowCount="4"/>              
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="Asset Type:" required="true">
                    <mx:List id="asset" dataProvider="{assetDP}" labelField="value" allowMultipleSelection="true" rowCount="4"/>                    
                </mx:FormItem>

                <mx:FormItem label="From Date:" required="true">
                    <mx:DateField id="fromDate" yearNavigationEnabled="true"/>       
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:FormItem label="To Date:" required="true">      
                    <mx:DateField id="toDate" yearNavigationEnabled="true"/>         
                </mx:FormItem>
                <mx:Button label="Submit" click="getReport()" toolTip="Exposure Report." />
                <mx:Button label="Save To Excel" click="exportToExcel();"/>                                 
        </mx:HBox>
        <mx:VBox height="85%" width="100%">     
            <mx:DataGrid id="dataGrid" height="100%" width="100%" dataProvider="{reportDG}" horizontalScrollPolicy="on">               
                <mx:columns>
                    <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="alertId" headerText="Alert ID" showDataTips="true" dataTipField="alertId"/>


                </mx:columns>
            </mx:DataGrid>
        </mx:VBox>
    </mx:VDividedBox>
</mx:Canvas>
```

**ERROR**
EventDispatcher.js:74 Uncaught TypeError: indicatorClass is not a constructor
    at mx.containers.FormItem.mx_containers_FormItem_displayIndicator (FormItem.js:718)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.updateDisplayList (FormItem.js:397)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.updateFormItemDisplayList (FormItem.js:409)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.updateDisplayList (FormItem.js:1101)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.mx.containers.beads.BoxLayout.layout (BoxLayout.js:115)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.org.apache.royale.core.LayoutBase.performLayout (LayoutBase.js:247)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.FormItemLayout.org.apache.royale.core.LayoutBase.handleLayoutNeeded (LayoutBase.js:152)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.goog.events.EventTarget.fireListeners (eventtarget.js:284)
    at Function.goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEventInternal_ (eventtarget.js:381)
    at mx.containers.FormItem.goog.events.EventTarget.dispatchEvent (eventtarget.js:196

Comment: Hi Ravikanth, this kind of answer is too generic. I can give you some points, but will be difficult to connect the multiple parts here to that points. As well there's parts like "How can I load view within view with depth of N times" not easy to understand what you are referring. I propose you break this in new answers more short with specific doubts or problems you have, so we can help you.

Comment: Hi @CarlosRovira I have updated my question Can you please go through the question again. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

my advice if that you start from a simple working file and start adding things to it.

In Royale there's no only one UI set like in Flex (MX/Spark). You can choose between Basic, Jewel, Emulation (MX/Spark), MDL. So first thing is: What UI Set you want to choose?. Take into account that Emulation (MX/Spark) is still a work in progress and is not fully working. Maybe Jewel or Basic will be more easy to do, but you require to adapta your UI code to this new tags and APIs.

For example, in Jewel you can check [Tour de Jewel](https://royale.apache.org/tourdejewel/) and the [source code](https://github.com/apache/royale-asjs/blob/develop/examples/royale/TourDeJewel) to see how it's done

HTH